# Foundation 6 Libsass config

Tags: zurb-foundation-6, libsass

If I was using Compass to compile SASS partials to CSS, then I could specify input directory (say ‘scss’) and output (again, say ‘css’) in the *ruby* config.rb file. This is how I used to compile Foundation 5.

Instead I’ve Installed Zurb Foundation 6 using the CLI and am watching and compiling with Libsass (written in C?). It’s really quick, but...

Where is the equivalent config file, to change the default directories?

Comment: Im interesting about it too (i want to switch from sass + compass to libsass) and im missing some config file where is possible to set path to css, images, set relative / absolute path etc.

is there anything like that?